# Is it possible to become a SDET(QA Automated) without having experience, with the free paths of Test Automation University from Applittols?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, manual-testing, test-design, sdet

I'm new in the community.

I have worked for several years as a programmer maintaining code and fixing bugs of ready-made applications.

Thanks for your answers,
Best regards.

Reference
https://testautomationu.applitools.com/learningpaths.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes but also no. Learning and writing some tests that are on your github that you can talk about the lessons you learned, definitely. Some random course like the one you linked, LinkedIn learning, etc. I wouldn't count ok getting you very far. You might also want to go for the ISTQB cert to learn the foundations and it is one of the few recognized QA certificates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: How does ISTQB make you a better tester, or coding tester or whoever really? I have some of these certs myself and it was just a waste of time and money. If I read one of the first sentences in ISTQB foundation sylabus ("Software testing is a way to assess the quality of the 
software and to reduce the risk of software failure in operation")... how does this make any sense? It's just nonsense. I don't doubt it might open some doors in companies that have poor standards when it comes to testing, but that's it.

Comment: Getting/Showing a foundation-level knowledge of testing concepts is good if you are not a tester. A few (not many) companies look for ISTQB. When considering a certification look for how many job postings list it in the requirements/nice-to-haves. Get a cert or just go read Foundation of Software Testing by Glenford Myers. The question was about becoming an SDET, not a better SDET.

Answer (score 1):

Test Automation University courses are excellent for introduction to a certain automation tool or concept but they will not make you a SDET or test automator.

What you need to do after passing a TAU course is actually applying what you have learned on a project and consolidating and expanding on your knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.